# I want to create a newline containing incrementing numbers between each line of text

Tags: perl

I have lines of text as follows:

```
The cat and the mouse
Were in the house
They spotted some grouse
```

I want to put a new line between each line of text with an incrementing number after a ">" so that it looks like this

```
>1
The cat and the mouse
>2
Were in the house
>3
They spotted some grouse
```

I would like to do this in perl if possible s I can run it on a mac. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl from command line,

```
perl -pe 's|^|>$.$/|' file
```

`$.` is current line number, and `$/` is input record separator (usually newline `\n`)

Comment: Awesome. How would I then save the result to a txt file rather than it printing out on the terminal?

Comment: @user3632206 you can redirect output to file by adding `> file2` or do in place edit `perl -i -pe ..`

Comment: Actually I was trying to upvote it as it did exactly what I wanted it to, but now Im locked out for a few hours

Comment: It told me my vote had been locked in and I couldnt change it unless I edited it. I could have sworn I upvoted the answer as it was really useful. Guess Ill try tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
perl -pe 'print ">$.\n"' foo.txt
```